# Adding an iif statement or where clause

Tags: reporting-services, iif

Here is my current expression

```
=IIf(Fields!Units_Sold.Value = 0, 0, Fields!Total_Incidents.Value / IIf(Fields!Units_Sold.Value = 0, 1, Fields!Units_Sold.Value))
```

I need to add where Fields!.TECHNOLOGY = "Wired" to the above statement I tried a couple different things but with no success.

Comment: Explain what you have to filter. Do you need the total incidents/total units sold where technology is wired?

Comment: yes, total incidents/total units sold where technology = wired

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 =IIf(Sum(iif(Fields!technology.Value = "wired",Fields!Units_Sold.Value,0)) = 0,
 0,
 sum(iif(Fields!technology.Value="wired",Fields!Total_Incidents.Value,0)) /
 IIf(Sum(iif(Fields!technology.Value = "wired",
 Fields!Units_Sold.Value,0)) = 0, 1,
 Sum(iif(Fields!technology.Value = "wired",Fields!Units_Sold.Value,0))
 )
 )
```

It is not tested but should work. Let me know if this could help you